# generate pdf with more than 50000 records

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf, fpdf, mpdf

Hi I am trying to generate a transaction report of more than 500000 records, I tried mPDF, FPDF, TCPDF.

All of above creates error

```
<i>Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6180881 bytes) in J:\shaonline\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 20476</i>
```

I tried to set memory size to 1024M and time out to 30M but still same error.
on records less then 1000 it works fine.

Comment: Have you considered using a separate service to generate those PDFs outside PHP?

Comment: You may be able to generate a lot of 10 page PDF's and merge them together with another tool afterwards?

Comment: @MMM can you share some more details? I got idea to run from command line but no idea how to exec commandline.

Answer (score 2):

I would not do this since all of these librarys AFAIK hold the complete PDF stream in memory until they write it out to disk. Export your data into, e.g. XML, and use another technique to convert it into PDF, such as XSL-FO.